# Python : how to speed up this file loading

Tags: python, performance, file-io, codec

I am seeking for a way to speed up a file loading like this :

The data contains about 1 millions lines, tab separated with "\t" (tabulation char) and utf8 encoding, it takes about 9 seconds to parse the full file with the code below. However, I would have like to be almost in an order of a second!

```
def load(filename):
    features = []
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f:
        previous = ""
        for n, s in enumerate(f):
            splitted = tuple(s.rstrip().split("\t"))
            if len(splitted) != 2:
                sys.exit("wrong format!")
            if previous >= splitted:
                sys.exit("unordered feature")
            previous = splitted
            features.append(splitted)
    return features
```

I am wondering if any binary format data could speed up something? Or if I could benefit from a some `NumPy` or any other libraries to have faster loading speed.

Maybe you could give me advice on another speed bottleneck?

**EDIT:** so i try some of your ideas, thanks! BTW i really need the tuple (string, string) inside the huge list... here are the results, i'm gaining 50% of the time :) now i am going to look after the NumPy binary data, as i have noticed that another huge file was really really quick to load...

```
import codecs

def load0(filename): 
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f: 
    return f.readlines() 

def load1(filename): 
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f: 
    return [tuple(x.rstrip().split("\t")) for x in f.readlines()]

def load3(filename):
    features = []
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f:
    for n, s in enumerate(f):
        splitted = tuple(s.rstrip().split("\t"))
        features.append(splitted)
    return features

def load4(filename): 
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f: 
    for s in f: 
        yield tuple(s.rstrip().split("\t")) 

a = datetime.datetime.now()
r0 = load0(myfile)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print "f.readlines(): %s" % (b-a)

a = datetime.datetime.now()
r1 = load1(myfile)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print """[tuple(x.rstrip().split("\\t")) for x in f.readlines()]: %s""" % (b-a)

a = datetime.datetime.now()
r3 = load3(myfile)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print """load3: %s""" % (b-a)
if r1 == r3: print "OK: speeded and similars!"

a = datetime.datetime.now()
r4 = [x for x in load4(myfile)] 
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print """load4: %s""" % (b-a)
if r4 == r3: print "OK: speeded and similars!"
```

results :

```
f.readlines(): 0:00:00.208000
[tuple(x.rstrip().split("\t")) for x in f.readlines()]: 0:00:02.310000
load3: 0:00:07.883000
OK: speeded and similars!
load4: 0:00:07.943000
OK: speeded and similars!
```

something very strange is that i notice that i can have almost double time on two consecutive runs (but not everytime) :

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
f.readlines(): 0:00:00.220000
[tuple(x.rstrip().split("\t")) for x in f.readlines()]: 0:00:02.479000
load3: 0:00:08.288000
OK: speeded and similars!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
f.readlines(): 0:00:00.279000
[tuple(x.rstrip().split("\t")) for x in f.readlines()]: 0:00:04.983000
load3: 0:00:10.404000
OK: speeded and similars!
```

**EDIT LATEST:** well i tried to modify to use the `numpy.load`... it is very strange to me... from "normal" file with my 1022860 strings, and 10 KB. 
After doing a `numpy.save(numpy.array(load1(myfile)))` i went to a 895 MB ! an then reloading this with `numpy.load()` i get this kind of timing on consecutive runs :

```
  >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
  loading: 0:00:11.422000 done.
  >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
  loading: 0:00:00.759000 done.
```

may be does numpy do some memory stuff to avoid future reload?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you compare strings `previous` and `splitted` the way you do? Have you looked into list comprehension? For example, see [this related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130262/how-do-i-efficiently-filter-computed-values-within-a-python-list-comprehension).

Comment: actually this comparison is just a way to ensure that the file format is ok. Removing these 2 tests i only gain 09.09 => 08.38 seconds. My real problem is how can i read a file mixing tuple(string, string) tab separated as fast as possible. I almost can remove these tests, BTW doing this, i am still 7 seconds too slow :/

Comment: Do you really need to collect all the "features" in a big list? Maybe you can just traverse the lines by making this a generator function, and iterate over that.

Comment: @Keith, well i do not know, actually i am trying to speed up an external library (mit licence) that i wanted to embed in a webservice, i notice that the huge bottleneck was the loading of these features. I should dive more deeply to check if i can refactorize the whole thing... but it may not be my main priority - speeding it without rewriting everything, would be enough for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check how many seconds is to actually read the lines of the file, like

```
def load(filename):
    features = []
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f:
        return f.readlines()
```

If it is significantly less then 9 sec, then

1. try other to use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) and split the work of checking lines between cpu cores and/or
2. use faster interpreter like pypy

and see if any of these speed things up

Comment: looks like the fastest, as i load it f.readlines(): 0:00:00.208000 BTW i also need the splitting, mixing with Burhan Khalid allow me to gain a lot of time... going to look if i can go in less 2 or 1 seconds... Numpy may be promising, if there is any compatible struct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this version, since you mentioned the checking wasn't important I have eliminated it.

```
def load(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'rb',  'utf-8') as f:
        for s in f:
            yield tuple(s.rstrip().split("\t"))

results = [x for x in load('somebigfile.txt')]
```

Comment: this is very strange, this method looks not particularly fast :/ see my load4 that is your suggestion, BTW inspired by your answer load1 is much more faster! i can not explain it... now i am going to check any Numpy binary way..

Answer (score 1):

Having checked how long does it take to just iterate over the file, as `bpgergo` suggests, you can check the following:

- If you know that your file contains 10^6 rows, you could preallocate the list. It should be faster than appending to it in each iteration. Just use `features = [None] * (10 ** 6)` to initialize your list
- Don't cast the result of `split()` onto tuple, it doesn't seem necessary.
- You don't seem to benefit from `enumerate` at all. Just use: `for line in f:` instead of `for n, s in enumerate(f):`

Comment: i think that the cast to tuple was necessary for the ordering check with `previous >= splitted` but i may be wrong...

Comment: @user1340802: `split()` returns a list, so it can be compared in just the same way as tuple. The only benefit from casting may be that the author needs immutable entries in later processing.

Comment: @Dougal: I didn't say he has to try all my advices simultaneously :)