# List comprehension with expensive computation

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I have a few list comprehensions that look like the following.

```
li = [some_computation(x) for x in y if some_computation(x)]
```

Where I only want the values that are truthy with respect to `some_computation`.

1. Does this compute `some_computation(x)` twice as the list comprehension makes it seem? If `some_computation` is expensive, I really **don't** want this. (I feel like this is probably the case `:(`)
2. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps to break it into a regular for loop and append if only if `some_computation(x)`, but I like comprehensions.

Comment: This has come up a few times before but can't seem to find it... anyway... you can nest a gen-exp inside your list-comp, eg: `li = [el for el in (some_func(x) for x in y) if el]`...

Comment: Yes, the `some_computation` function will be evaluated twice in both Python 2.x and 3.x

Comment: @JonClements I think I have found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130262/how-do-i-efficiently-filter-computed-values-within-a-python-list-comprehension?rq=1 Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

`some_computation` will be calculated twice, to avoid this you could use `filter` to discard the falsy results:

```
li = list(filter(None, (some_computation(x) for x in y)))
```

Or use a nested generator expression as Jon Clements suggests:

```
li = [el for el in (some_computation(x) for x in y) if el]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it does some_computation twice, try this and see:

   ```
   def compute(x):
       print("Compute...")
       return 2*x
   y=[1,3,5]
   ls=[compute(x) for x in y if compute(x)]
   ```

Output:

```
Compute...
Compute...
Compute...
Compute...
Compute...
Compute...
```

2. Better Python way:

   `ls=[x for x in [compute(z) for z in y] if x]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Does this compute some_computation(x) twice as the list comprehension makes it seem?

Yes. It computes twice.

2. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps to break it into a regular for loop and append if only if some_computation(x), but I like comprehensions.

You have to do regular looping. Generators are on the fly and not stored. Possibly you can take the algorithm for chosing the x out and do computation

```
li = [computation(x) for x in y if choose(x)]
```

Or you have to do iteration in the if condition which is equivalent to calling the computation twice.